# GPU-based astronomical software for MacOS/AMD/OpenCL environment

Tags: software

I notice that most astronomical software that uses GPUs to accelerate computation makes use of Nvidia's CUDA toolkit. Are there established software packages that, instead, can be used on a modern Mac with an AMD GPU and the OpenCL GPGPU environment?

I'm specifically looking for transient detection and pulsar search tools (radio astronomy). Bonus points if they are open source.